# Unable to replay selenium tests on https url from browserstack

Tags: selenium, browserstack

**pre-req**: Selenium Java 3.141/Browserstack

Below is my sample code and first trial with browserstack.

```
public class testbrowserstack {

  public static final String USERNAME = "dat";
  public static final String AUTOMATE_KEY = "234fwer3424dewft4a";
  public static final String URL = "https://" + USERNAME + ":" + AUTOMATE_KEY + "@hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setCapability("acceptSslCerts", "true");
    caps.setCapability("browserName", "iPhone");
    caps.setCapability("device", "iPhone 8 Plus");
    caps.setCapability("realMobile", "true");
    caps.setCapability("os_version", "11");
    caps.setCapability("name", "Bstack-[Java] Sample Test");

    WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(URL), caps);
    driver.get("https://vdevpri.com/login");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.quit();

  }
```

**Expected output**: https url should be navigated

**Actual output**: Safari browser gets open but doesn't navigates to given URL

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are accessing an internal URL that is accessible only from your network, you will have to enable [BrowserStack Local Testing](https://www.browserstack.com/local-testing).